# when using ruby gem httparty: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: ruby, docker, jenkins

While running the below code in jenkins at HTTParty.post step we are getting error httparty: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate). All the SSL cerificates were installed in docker only at this line it is failing

```
require 'httparty'

HTTParty.post(TOKEN_PATH,
              basic_auth: {
                             :CLIENT_ID,
                             :CLIENT_SECRET
                           },
              body: { grant_type: 'client_credentials',scope: '' }                             
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to ignore the ssl verification, from there you can try to improve if you want to check your certs.

```
require 'httparty'
HTTParty::Basement.default_options.update(verify: false)

HTTParty.post(TOKEN_PATH,
              basic_auth: {
                             :CLIENT_ID,
                             :CLIENT_SECRET
                           },
              body: { grant_type: 'client_credentials',scope: '' }
```

)